# Apache2 - line folding encountered before the first header line

Tags: apache, http, http-headers, load-balancing, cherrypy

I have setup a load-balancer using apache2 on an aws EC2 instance. My vhosts config looks like this

```
Listen 4433

<VirtualHost *:4433>

ServerName v1app.xxx.tech
ServerAlias www.v1app.xxx.tech
ServerAdmin magistrate@v1app.xxx.tech

SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /srv/certs/cert.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /srv/certs/privkey.pem
SSLCertificateChainFile /srv/certs/chain.pem

ProxyRequests Off
ProxyVia Off

<Proxy *>
  Order deny,allow
  Allow from all
</Proxy>

<Proxy "balancer://mycluster">
BalancerMember "http://10.0.0.252:4433"
BalancerMember "http://10.0.1.243:4433"
BalancerMember "http://10.0.1.179:4433"
BalancerMember "http://10.0.2.252:4433"
ProxySet lbmethod=byrequests
</Proxy>
ProxyPass "/" "balancer://mycluster/"
ProxyPassReverse "/" "balancer://mycluster"

</VirtualHost>
```

We have devices requesting a file download with incorrect header formatting. The http request made by the device looks like this

```
GET https://xxx:4433/firmware_update HTTP/1.0
        authorization: smoker CCB8A85813F0
```

When I check the error.log on my apache load balancer, I see it is unable to parse the header and says "line folding encountered before the first header line". However, the malformed requests still works well with our cherryPy server without the load balancer in between.
When I remove the extra 8 spaces before the authorization header, the requests works well and I am able to download the file on device.

Now, it clearly is an issue on the device code, but we have hundreds of devices already manufactured and there is no way to change the code on device.

Is there any way we can modify the apache load balancer config or by disabling/enabling apache modules to make it less stringent in regards to header parsing. Or is there any other server/load balancer application which will be able to handle the above malformed header. Or would it be possible to setup a load balancer using CherryPy ?

Comment: Please ask for any additional information or logs in comments if needed

Comment: You could try having a small CherryPy web-app doing redirects to other hosts, in case your devices are capable of following redirects.